# Best way to denote some trigonometric functions ("tg" vs "tan", "ctg" vs "cot")

Tags: trigonometry, notation

What is the best way to denote tangent and other trigonometric functions: **tg** or **tan**, **ctg** or **cot**. What notation is commonly used and standardized?

Comment: FWIW: I'd not say $\tan$ and $\cot$ are "best", but they are the notation that more people understand than $\mathrm{tg}$ and $\mathrm{ctg}$. So, if you're writing for a wide audience, you might consider using the more popular ones.

Comment: @J.M.ain'tamathematician: I bet in China they use tg (and I am sure about x-USSR countries). I do not know about India and Pakistan. Perhaps they use tan which they used when they were parts of British empire (just as the cricket). So a lot of people use tg.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In current US textbooks, $\tan$ and $\cot$ are commonly used and standardized.  Also: $\sin, \cos, \sec, \csc$. In other countries, and in the 19th century, you will find others.

Answer (score 7):

Standard

ISO 80000-2 *Quantities and units — Part 2: Mathematical signs and symbols to be
used in the natural sciences and technology*

is perfectly clear: the right symbols are $\tan x$ (item 2-13.4) and $\cot x$ (item 2-13.5).

To cite the standard: "$\text{tg } x$, $\text{ctg } x$ should not be used."

Comment: +1. Do you have a source for the ISO passages? The only thing I can find on ISO.org is [an unhelpful preview and a link to purchase the document](https://www.iso.org/standard/31887.html); perhaps I didn't look hard enough. The Wikipedia ["ISO 80000-2" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_80000-2) only makes passing reference to "sin" and "tanh" (and "arcsin" and "artanh"). (Interestingly, the entry reports that "$\sin^{-1}$" and "$\tanh^{-1}$" aren't included in the standard. I'm not sure what to think about that.)

Comment: @Blue I have access to these standards.  They are rather expensive, so their publisher is doing everything it can to disable free access.  If you have a specific question I can look into standard for you.

Comment: It is worth noting that these standards are directed towards scientists and engineers in industry, and have little to do with the lives of working mathematicians in academia.  They are a useful reference, but, at the end of the day, mathematicians aren't beholden to any standards body, and the best advice is "do what your editor / reviewer / instructor tells you to do."

Comment: @XanderHenderson In certain areas, standards are enforced. In others, they are voluntary. But even in the latter case, they can help to ease communication between different groups regarding geography and subject study. For example, I personally would prefer a world where everyone uses the same symbol for tangens, so there is less confusion. In my small country, both tan and tg are used, the former mostly by mathematicians and the latter mostly by the others.

Comment: @Pygmalion Nothing you have written contradicts me at all.  However much you would like a world in which everyone uses the same symbols, that simply isn't the world we live in.  Published standards are fine, but, again, professional mathematicians are not beholden to those standards.  We are beholden to our editors, reviewers, advisors, department chairs, instructors, etc.  So... standards are nice, but are irrelevant to most working mathematicians.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I did not mean to contradict you, but to supplement you. It would be nice if the editors / instructors themselves would adhere to some published standards (not necessarily ISO) or at least allow the authors to do so. However, relevance is in the eye of the beholder, i.e. let the readers of my response to decide on that.

Comment: @Pygmalion, I am very sorry, I am bothering you because you said “if you have a specific question I can look into standard for you”, I have few very specific questions: what ISO 80000-2 says for cosecant (“cosec _x_” or “csc _x_”), hyperbolic functions (“ch _x_” or “cosh _x_”, “sh _x_” or “sinh _x_”, etc) and inverse functions (“arcsin _x_”, “asin _x_” or “sin⁻¹ _x_”, etc)?

Comment: @Sasha cosecant is `csc`. Obviously the idea is to keep three-letters abbreviations for trigonometric functions. When you want to get reverse, just add `arc` at the start, hence `arctan`, `arccsc`.  When you have hyperbolic functions, you add `h` at the end, hence `tanh`, `csch`.  When you want to get reverse, add `ar` at the start, hence `artanh`, `arcsch`.  Everything is pretty logical, except for `ar`; I'd personaly prefer `arctanh` and `arccsch`.  But I never used inverses of hyperbolic in my life :)

Comment: @Pygmalion, thank you very much! (And just a bit of off-topic emotions… `artanh` – OMG, I never expected it to be `ar*`. And `arcsch` is even worse: I attempt to parse it as `ArcSch` instead of `ArCscH` – I was even starting to write “@Pygmalion, you probably have a typo there” (until I got it). IMHO, that's quite pointless to force them to be 3- and 6- letter. For us, they were always `tg`, `ctg`; `sh`, `ch`, `th` (`cth`); `arc*`. And, yep, just recently I suddenly benefited from `sh` and `ArcSh` in my work, but the work is quite geometry-related, so that's not so unexpected.)

Comment: @sasha Actually, trigonometric functions are three-letters, and reverse of trigonometric are six-letters.  Hyperbolic functions are FOUR-letters, so it makes sense that reverse of hyperbolic functions are SEVEN-letters.  So insisting on six-letters for reverse of hyperbolic functions makes no sense.  Otherwise, I have no objections to fix trigonometric and reverse of trigonometric to 3 and 6 letters.  In my childhood we also used `tg` and `ctg`, but I see that nowadays my colleagues mathematicians use `tan` and `cot` consistently, so I use them as well to avoid confusion with students.

Comment: @Pygmalion, yep, I agree that insisting on six-letters for reverse of hyperbolic functions makes no sense. But, IIUC, that's what exactly in ISO for now. Thank you very much for providing details about ISO 80000-2.

Answer (score 5):

Some people are familiar with **tg** and some people are familiar with **tan**.So, for wide use just define the notation.It solve your's problem I think.